# Quasinormal subgroup which is not nomal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am searching for an easy example of a subgroup which is quasinormal but not normal. Please help.

Comment: What does "quasinormal" mean?

Comment: $H$ Quasinormal means $HK=KH$ for all subgroups $K$.

Answer (score 1):

This is answered in [the Wiki page on quasinormal subgroups.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasinormal_subgroup)

Comment: Wiki page does not explain the reason.

Comment: It gives a construction, which you can work out.

Comment: it will be better if you explain the construction a little bit.